# matplotlib minor ticks not showing with one major tick

Tags: matplotlib

I am new to this space and i'm working with matplotlib for a while .
Here is my problem : as you can see when i have two or more major ticks `a1.plot(date2, closep2)` then perfect no problem but with one major tick `a1.plot(date1, closep1)` i get no minor .
can any one help please ? i will be grateful .

```css
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import datetime as dt
from random import randint

fig = plt.figure
a1 = plt.subplot(111)

d= 1536596330   #just an starting time for my sample data
date1= []
date2= []
closep1 = []
closep2 = []

# Not the best way but making some lists to plot :
# Date1 with 48 dates and 30 minutes interval , some random prices
for hh in range (0, 48) :
 dates= dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d+ (hh*1800)))
 date1.append(dates)
 closep1.append(randint(1,9))

# Date2 with 72 dates and 30 minutes interval , some random prices
for hh in range (0, 72) :
 dates= dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d+ (hh*1800)))
 date2.append(dates)
 closep2.append(randint(1,9))

# Here comes trouble :
a1.plot(date1, closep1)

# No problem with this one :
# a1.plot(date2, closep2)

a1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
a1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b/%d'))
a1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mticker.AutoMinorLocator(6))
a1.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.setp(a1.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(),rotation=45, fontsize=10,color='k')
plt.setp(a1.xaxis.get_minorticklabels(),rotation=45, fontsize=7,color='r')

plt.show()
```

[1 major tick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGagV.png)
[2 major ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XeMK.png)

Comment: `6` in `AutoMinorLocator(6)`  means divide the region between major ticks in 6 equal divisions thereby resulting in 5 minor ticks. When you have one major tick, I think it doesn't find the next major tick to divide the region in between and hence no minor ticks

Comment: @Bazingga , thank you for your answer . truth is even `AutoMinorLocator(24)` or any other not working but  `mdates.DayLocator(1)` will start plot with day one as major 1 and end with day two as major 2 also minors showing up but not good enough

Comment: If there is only one major then it doesn't matter if you choose 6 or 16 or 24 or 100... Doesn't my solution below work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one cheap hack. I am only showing the code modified.

```
for hh in range(0, 58): # Increased the range
    dates= dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d+ (hh*1800)))
    date1.append(dates)
    closep1.append(randint(1,9))

# Plotting the complete range in white color to get the major ticks
a1.plot(date1, closep1, color='white') 
a1.plot(date1[0:48], closep1[0:48]) # Plotting the wanted data only up to 48 in color
```

**Output**

[image]